# Async table query in sequelize getter method

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, sequelize.js, getter

I have a sequelize instance method that performs a DB query:

```
getPropertyDays() {
    const queryString = `
      SELECT
        state
      FROM property_days
      WHERE
        DATE(day) = CURDATE() AND
        property_id = :propertyId;`;

    const replacements = {propertyId: this.id};
    return this.sequelize.query(queryString, {replacements: replacements, type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT});
  },
```

that gets called by the getter:

```
getterMethods: {
  propertyState() {
    var self = this;
    const blockedDay = 'x';
    const unavailableDay = 'u';

    this.getPropertyDays().then(function(result) {
      var state = result[0]['state'];

      if (self.prospect || state == unavailableDay) {
        return 'unavailable';
      }
      if (state == blockedDay) {
        return 'occupied';
      }
      else {
        return 'available';
      }
    });
  }
},
```

The problem is that the result that is returned from the getter is undefined because he's not able to solve the promise before returning.

Since I don't have a model for the table, how can I solve this issue? Been around this for one day already!

Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you please share how you have solved this issue

Answer (score 0):

Won't returning the promise returned from `this.getPropertyDays` do the trick?

```
getterMethods: {
  propertyState() {
    var self = this;
    const blockedDay = 'x';
    const unavailableDay = 'u';

    return this.getPropertyDays().then(function(result) {
      var state = result[0]['state'];

      if (self.prospect || state == unavailableDay) {
        return 'unavailable';
      }
      if (state == blockedDay) {
        return 'occupied';
      }
      else {
        return 'available';
      }
    });
  }
},
```

Comment: Not really from my experimentation.  For instance, the model's toJSON will output the properties of the promise vs. the resolved value of the promise, which isn't all that helpful.